# How configure a Minimum of messages do read - Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

Is possible to configure a Minimum of messages for Kafka read ?

Example I would like my consumer start to read the messages of topic after arrive 5 or more messages.

I tried use max-poll-interval-ms with fetch-max-wait-ms and max-poll-records, but the kafka continued reading one by one.

Comment: can you show the code and configs, but still there is no guarantee that these properties will effect when there is low throughput

Comment: consumer.max-poll-interval-ms=10000
consumer.fetch-max-wait-ms=10000
consumer.max-poll-records= 20

Comment: When I start my consumer and there are for example 100 messages in the topic, ok my consumer read 20 by 20 messages, but when the topic is empty and I send one or two messages the consumer start to read one by one.

Comment: Yes that's the consumer behaviour, when it has sufficient messages it reads on limit, but when there is less messages it will poll availiable ones @LuizJunior

Comment: You cannot specify a minimum number of records, you can only approximate, by specifiying a minimum number of bytes (`fetch.min.bytes` together with `fetch.max.wait.ms`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify a minimum number of records, you can only approximate, by specifiying a minimum number of bytes (`fetch.min.bytes` together with `fetch.max.wait.ms`).